# Python Pandas: How to groupby aggregate using a function that returns pd.Series

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a multiindexed dataframe on which I want to aggregate over some of the indices. If the aggregator function returns a float, things work with no problem. But I can't find how to use a function with more complex returns (e.g., a pd.Series). Using a function that returns pd.Series gives me this error: `Exception: Must produce aggregated value` error.

Here is an example dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'A': {
        (1, 0): 85, (1, 1): 75,
        (2, 0): 12, (2, 1): 15,
        (3, 0): 2,  (3, 1): 26,
    },
    'B': {
        (1, 0): 86, (1, 1): 76,
        (2, 0): 13, (2, 1): 17,
        (3, 0): 19, (3, 1): 18,
    }
}).stack()
df.index.rename(['idx', 'bar', 'label'], inplace=True)
```

The content of `df` is:

```
idx  bar  label
1    0    A        85
          B        86
     1    A        75
          B        76
2    0    A        12
          B        13
     1    A        15
          B        17
3    0    A         2
          B        19
     1    A        26
          B        18
dtype: int64
```

Let's define a simple aggregator that returns pd.Series:

```
def my_func(subframe):
  subframe = subframe.unstack('label')
  mean_A_plus_B = np.mean(subframe['B'] + subframe['A'])
  mean_A_minus_B = np.mean(subframe['B'] - subframe['A'])
  return pd.Series([mean_A_plus_B, mean_A_minus_B], index=['A+B', 'A-B'])
  # return mean_A_plus_B  ## <- this one works.
```

Applying the aggregator like the following an exception:

```
df.groupby('idx').agg(my_func)
.
.
.
py/pandas/core/groupby/generic.py in _aggregate_named(self, func, *args, **kwargs)
    907             output = func(group, *args, **kwargs)
    908             if isinstance(output, (Series, Index, np.ndarray)):
--> 909                 raise Exception('Must produce aggregated value')
    910             result[name] = self._try_cast(output, group)

Exception: Must produce aggregated value
```

What I had hoped to receive was:

```
       A+B    A-B
idx
1    161.0    1.0
2     28.5    1.5
3     32.5    4.5
dtype: float64
```

What is the right way of doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just replace `.agg()` by `.apply()`:

```
df.groupby('idx').apply(my_func).unstack(level=-1)
```

Output:

```
       A+B  A-B
idx            
1    161.0  1.0
2     28.5  1.5
3     32.5  4.5
```

Comment: Now I have a follow up problem. the `.agg()` method can receive a *dict of column names -> functions (or list of functions)* according to the documentation. It looks like that `apply` has no such capability. My use case is that I have a bunch of column specific processing that I want to run on a dataframe. I wanted to pass `{'col1': func_a, 'col2': func_b, ...}` type argument to it. Any idea if there's a work around for that?

Comment: You can do that with `.apply()` as well, by processing different columns in your `my_func` and returning a DataFrame, instead of a Series